# Transposing specific rows to columns

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have millions of lines like this. I want to write simple bash script to get some information.

```
                            Name:                 1FJ
                        HA_RMSDs:          -1000.0000
                        HA_RMSDh:          -1000.0000
                        HA_RMSDm:              0.0000
                      Grid_Score:          -24.958729
                 Grid_vdw_energy:          -24.958729
                  Grid_es_energy:            0.000000
       Internal_energy_repulsive:            5.894002
                            Name:       ZINC103990867
                        HA_RMSDs:          -1000.0000
                        HA_RMSDh:          -1000.0000
                        HA_RMSDm:              0.0000
                      Grid_Score:          -22.196136
                 Grid_vdw_energy:          -17.917459
                  Grid_es_energy:           -4.278677
       Internal_energy_repulsive:           14.832469
```

I want to get like this;

```
Name            Grid_Score
ZINC103990867   -22.196136
1FJ             -24.958729
```

I have found some [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79642/transposing-rows-and-columns) but I could not do it.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have name to value mappings in your input it's usually best to first create an array holding those mappings and  then just print the values by their names:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ sub(/:/,"") }

NR==1 { key=$1 }
$1==key { prt() }
{ f[$1] = $2 }
END { prt() }

function prt(   i) {
    if (NR==1) {
        numCols = split(c,cols,/,/)
        for (i=1; i<=numCols; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", cols[i], (i<numCols?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
    else {
        for (i=1; i<=numCols; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", f[cols[i]], (i<numCols?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v c='Name,Grid_Score' -f tst.awk file | column -t
Name           Grid_Score
1FJ            -24.958729
ZINC103990867  -22.196136
```

.

```
$ awk -v c='Name,Grid_Score,HA_RMSDs,Grid_es_energy' -f tst.awk file | column -t
Name           Grid_Score  HA_RMSDs    Grid_es_energy
1FJ            -24.958729  -1000.0000  0.000000
ZINC103990867  -22.196136  -1000.0000  -4.278677
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk has a printf() statement if you need fancier formatting than this.

```
% awk 'BEGIN{print "Name","Grid_Score"}$1=="Name:"{name=$2}$1=="Grid_Score:"{print name,$2}' inputfile.txt
```

Comment: What do I need to do for sequential printing in ascending order? @keithpjolley

Comment: If you need pretty output, pipe plain awk output into `column -t`